# google analytics is showing an odd page on my site

Tags: php, google-analytics

We pushed a small UI change to the site last night. The google analytics code is in the header and has not been touched at all (entire header for the site and all the pages have not been touched at all)

Since the change, we are seeing a lot of hits logged to the page "/site/loading" which is not a page on our site. Even when we visit the site to test, we are occasionally seeing the active page show up as "/site/loading" instead of "/" or the specific page we are visiting. The pages are loading fine and the site is working fine. The error is happening somewhat randomly. Occasionally when someone visits the home page, it shows up as "/site/loading" and occasionally shows up correctly as "/"

Unclear why this is happening or what we might have done to trigger this changed behavior. Until yesterday, our tracking seemed fairly accurate.

Appreciate any ideas or suggestions

Comment: What was the nature of the UI change?

Comment: Yeah, sorry, not sure what's going on without getting a closer look at your setup. Have you tried looking at the networking calls / redirects that are happening?

Comment: This doesn't sound like some kind of standard HTTP behavior. If your site is redirecting to a different endpoint then it's probably something someone changed on your backend.

Comment: We aren't redirecting at all. If you go directly to that page, it shows up on analytics as "/site/loading" and that page isn't redirecting anywhere

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is an javascript in your page that loads that page (which leads to a 404 page that contains you tag management/analytics code). Around Line 935 in the code you have:

```
var urlToLoading = '/site/loading';
    function attachModalForJobs() {
        .......
            $('#modal-external-site').on('hidden.bs.modal', function (e) {
                $('#modal-external-site').find('iframe').attr('src', urlToLoading );
```

I assume that's where the logged url originates.

Comment: I think you are right. We will fix that. Thanks so much. I would vote up your answer but I need a minimum reputation to do that so sorry about that

Comment: If it turns out that this was  right you can still accept it :-)

Answer (score 1):

Next time just do a search for the url endpoint in your codebase....

```
var urlToLoading = '/site/loading';
function attachModalForJobs() {
    $('.listing-job').find('.title a').click(function(e){
        e.preventDefault();
        var link = $(this);
        $('#modal-external-site').modal();

        $('#modal-external-site').on('shown.bs.modal', function (e) {
            var modal = $('#modal-external-site');
            var bodyHeight = modal.find('.modal-content').height()-modal.find('.modal-header').outerHeight(true)-modal.find('.modal-footer').outerHeight(true)-20;

            modal.find('.modal-body').height(bodyHeight);    
            //modal.find('.modal-body').load(link.attr('href'));
            modal.find('iframe').attr('src', link.attr('href') );
            modal.find('iframe').attr('height', bodyHeight );
            modal.find('iframe').css('height', bodyHeight+'px');

            //$('iframe').contents().find('body').addClas('transform');

            //var head = $('iframe').contents().find('head');                
            //head.append($('<link/>', { rel: 'stylesheet', href: 'http://dev.tapwage.com/themes/dark/css/tapwage.min.css', type: 'text/css' }));
        });
        $('#modal-external-site').on('hidden.bs.modal', function (e) {
            $('#modal-external-site').find('iframe').attr('src', urlToLoading );
        });
    });
}
```